# How to apply css mark on videogular time line at specific time

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, videogular

I have an html player application where user can search a term ,then its populate the result with the time where those words occurs.On clicking that specific sentence the html player starts playing from that location.
But with this functionality I want to add some mark on the videogular time line as we see in youtube .

[image]

Like youtube you can see the yellow marker at specific time..same way i want the css marker at the particular location.
[image]

on right side search box if there is a sentence at 19:00 min then i want to set yellow marker at 19:00 ofvideogular timeline.

on click event of search button:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default side-search" type="button" data-ng-click="inlinSearch()"></button>
```

JS:

```
var onSearchSuccess = function (response) {
    $scope.inlineSearchResult = response.data;
    $scope.jsonResult = JSON.parse($scope.inlineSearchResult);
};
$scope.inlinSearch = function () {
    var counterSearch = 0;
    var textSearch = $scope.searchkey.toLowerCase().trim();
    scopraServices.searchWithin(textSearch, videoId)
                  .then(onSearchSuccess, function () {
                      alert("Search Operation failed");
                  });
};
```

Using ng-repeat I  am binding the value on view:

```
<section class="scroll-content-container">
<article class="scroll-content" data-ng-repeat="sr in jsonResult" data-ng-click="Seek(sr.Location)">
<a>[{{util.formatTime(sr.Location)}}]</a>
<p ng-bind-html=util.boldText(searchkey,sr.Result[0].Text)></p>
</article>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a demo: http://videogular.com/demo/#/cue-points
Full code example: https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/tree/master/app

Basically, add a few cuepoints to Videogular and style them with CSS. You have a directive to show your cue points (vg-scrub-bar-cue-points):

HTML

```
<videogular vg-cue-points="ctrl.config.cuePoints">
    <vg-media vg-src="ctrl.config.sources"></vg-media>

    <vg-controls>
        <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
        <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
            <vg-scrub-bar-cue-points class="myCuepoints"
                                     vg-cue-points="ctrl.config.cuePoints.myCuepoints"></vg-scrub-bar-cue-points>
        </vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-volume>
            <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
            <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
        </vg-volume>
        <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
    </vg-controls>

    <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
</videogular>
```

CSS

```
vg-scrub-bar-cue-points.myCustomCuepoints .cue-point {
    background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @elecaash.But inside controller,what values need to be passed to controller.config.cuePoints:

Comment: cuePoints: {
                        myCuepoints: [2,4,12,40]
                    },

Comment: It must be an array of objects, see docs for the object definition: http://videogular.com/docs/#/api/com.2fdevs.videogular.controller:vgController